# Создание БД Entity Framework Core

Tags: база-данных, entity-framework, проектирование

Использую `MS SQL Server` и `Entity Framework Core`, не получается правильно задать таблицы в БД.

У меня есть таблица `Item` - это товар. Таблица `Order` - заказ. В `Order` может быть много `Item`. `Item` не должен хранить информацию об `Order`. Для хранения информации о товарах в заказе есть отдельная таблица `ItemOrder`.

[image: схема БД]

**Item**

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

**Order**

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**ItemOrder**

```
public class ItemOrder
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

На данный момент, при создании БД, в таблицу `Item` добавляется поле `OrderId`, а мне надо, чтоб товары в заказе выносились в таблицу `ItemOrder`. Как можно указать это в коде `Entity Framework Core`?

Answer (score 0):

Удалось решить проблему, моя ошибка была в том, что я не правильно связывал таблицы.

**Item**

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public List<ItemOrder> ItemOrder { get; set; }
}
```

**Order**

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public List<ItemOrder> ItemOrder { get; set; }
}
```

И в контексте нужно прописать:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ItemOrder>().HasKey(t => new {t.ItemId, t.OrderId});

    modelBuilder.Entity<ItemOrder>()
        .HasOne(x => x.Item)
        .WithMany(x => x.ItemOrder)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.ItemId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ItemOrder>()
        .HasOne(x => x.Order)
        .WithMany(x => x.ItemOrder)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.OrderId);
}
```

Источник: [metanit](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/3.6.php)